# Azure Devops Scale Set Agent missing pwsh

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

Our DevOps pipeline has been running on Microsoft-hosted agents.  However, to help lock down our environment we are now moving to self-hosted agents (specifically, so we can deploy code to a Function App which has a private endpoint).

We have selected Scale Set Agents, and have got started by following [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops).  This has solved our immediate problem, in that our `AzureFunctionApp@1` tasks are running happily on the new agent pool.

However, we are struggling to run various other tasks on the new agents.  In particular, `PowerShell@2` and `AzureCLI@2` tasks are failing.  Presumably both rely on PowerShell; in both cases we are seeing the error:

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

I was expecting Azure Devops to configure the Scale Set Agents similarly to the Microsoft-hosted ones, but perhaps that is not the case.  Do I need to use a Custom Script Exetension to install PowerShell?

We are using the `UbuntuLTS` VM image, as per the guide linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting Azure Devops to configure the Scale Set Agents similarly to the Microsoft-hosted ones, but perhaps that is not the case.

It will not any tooling. The agent you installed just allows using the machine as build agent. Everything else must be part of the VM image or installed afterwards.

Sadly  MS cannot distribute their images but it is possible to build them for your own use: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/docs/create-image-and-azure-resources.md

Comment: OK, thanks @jikuja.  Does the `AzureFunctionApp@1` task work, just because it does not require any additional tooling?

Comment: Afaik the most of the built-in tasks are already using built-in node task runner. E.g. AzureCLI@2 has Script Type selection for PowerShell(ps), PowerShell Core(pscore), Batch(batch) and Shell(bash): https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV2/task.json#L49-L62 For me it looks like you have selected pwsh scripttype. Why AzureFunctionApp@1 instead of @2? For me it looks like AzureFunctionApp logic is written with built.in node.

Comment: You're right we are indeed specifying pscore, thanks for pointing that out.

As to AzureFunctionApp@1, I'm not sure there is a @2, but correct me if I'm wrong.  [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-v1?view=azure-pipelines)

Answer (score 1):

As @jikuja pointed out, the scale set agents you get from simply following the Microsoft guide are pretty empty, and have limited use.

The solution is indeed to build an image and apply it to the scale set.

For anyone (like me) wanting a shortcut to building and applying an image that looks like the Microsoft hosted agents, I would recomment having a look at this project: https://github.com/YannickRe/azuredevops-buildagents.